# Category URL Key redirect to Product Link

Tags: magento, url, categories, product

For example, I have this category that I want to redirect it to product page, is this possible?

For example I have Kati Birch Forest product, and it's url key is kati-birch-forest

[image]

Then I want this Corporate Gifts Url key **redirects** to kati-birch-forest product **INSTEAD** of the category's own url key.

[image]

How do we do this? Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the Magento admin Url Rewrite Management to get this to be done`(Admin->Catalog->Url Rewrite Management)`. In Magento it is possible to set any url of our choice for products and categories.

Another option is this, Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php` and then go to the `function _refreshProductRewrite`.
In this function, change: `'request_path' => $requestPath,` to: `'request_path' => 'products/'.$requestPath,`

This will change the product URL when creating the product, and when reindexing data for the old products and also helpful for SEO.